# Save to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've worked my way through the following [Google Maps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-infowindow).  There's a large notice saying the following

*Note: The signed-in feature is deprecated. Versions 3.27 and earlier of the Maps JavaScript API continue to support signed-in maps, but a future version will no longer support signed-in maps. Please watch the release notes for updates. (You can subscribe to the release notes.) Future versions of the Maps JavaScript API will continue to support features that save a place to Google Maps using an info window or the SaveWidget.*

I've tried using the SaveWidget and Info Window but it doesn't show any controls that allow you to **Save A Place**.  It only has a "View On Google Maps" link which takes you to Google Maps.  Is there a way to add a place to your saved places via a button without redirecting to Google Maps??  I think their definition of Save A Place is misleading...

Within the code example it also states this

```
//When you add a marker using a Place instead of a location, the Maps
//API will automatically add a 'Save to Google Maps' link to any info
//window associated with that marker.
```

Here is the code that shows the "View On Google Maps" link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save a Place</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      // When you add a marker using a Place instead of a location, the Maps
      // API will automatically add a 'Save to Google Maps' link to any info
      // window associated with that marker.
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: {lat: -33.8666, lng: 151.1958}
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          // Define the place with a location, and a query string.
          place: {
            location: {lat: -33.8666, lng: 151.1958},
            query: 'Google, Sydney, Australia'

          },
          // Attributions help users find your site again.
          attribution: {
            source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
            webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
          }
        });

        // Construct a new InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'Google Sydney'
        });

        // Opens the InfoWindow when marker is clicked.
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at their example, it seems that's the way it works now, even in 3.27. That said, the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#mode_place) has a Place mode that allows for direct saving to your maps.

Comment: Otherwise you should build your own [Maps URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide), such as https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Google%2C+Sydney%2C+Australia but this doesn't have a direct save functionality.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I shall investigate the Embed API.  Thanks, I'll let you know what I find!

Comment: If all you need to show is a simple map and a marker, then yes, that should be the solution. Otherwise if you are missing a way to save a map, have a look at the [feature requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853%20status:open%20type:feature_request) and if not requested already, ask for it... you never know ;)

Comment: @MrUpsidown no one has requested it but I starred one regarding the ability to download saved places.  Thanks for the link!